# Django filtering queryset

Tags: python, django

Here is my simple view:

```
def transaction_list(request):
    current_user = request.user
    month = datetime.date.today().month

    try:
        page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        page = 1

    objects = Transaction.objects.filter(user=current_user, date__month=month)
    p = Paginator(objects, 10, request=request)
    transactions = p.page(page)
    return render(request, 'transaction/list.html',
                  {'transactions': transactions})
```

It shows a list of transactions which occured in the current month.
I want to add an option to change the month of the transactions being displayed but I have no clue how to tackle this and make it work. Should it be done in a view? maybe template? I would appreciate any ideas

Comment: The only place you can do this is in the view, its unclear what the exact problem you're having is

Comment: @Sayse I just don't know how to change the month by which transactions are filtered and make django show this transactions in rendered template

Comment: I edited my answer to give you some more detail about django ajax handling.

Answer (score 0):

Take some time to read some Django docs as they may prove really valuable (not to mention they are very clean and well written for every version available). I would focus on [Working With Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/)

In short, you'll pass the month from your django template (maybe via ajax or a simple HTML form POST), to your view, and use your view function to get the POST data and use that in your queryset.

It is hard to provide a good, thorough answer because there are different ways to do this. Do you want AJAX? Simple form with page reload, etc?

---

Okay, here, in detail, is how I usually handle a POST request. This isn't tested code, it's just psuedo code, but *should* work as far as I can tell, aside from a few minor typos probably. BUT, it should give you an idea of how to handle ajax requests in Django.

This is pretty 101 and taking some time to read the docs and run through some of the early projects covers a these concepts much I, so my going into more depth isn't really valuable to SO readers.

views.py

```
class change_date_form(forms.Form):
    new_date = forms.DateField()

def change_transaction_date(request):
    #Do some checks to make sure user is authorized to do this
    current_user = ... 
    customer_data = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = change_date_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid():
           change_date = form.cleaned_data.get('new_date')
           objects = Transaction.objects.filter(user=current_user, date__month=change_date)
           for i in objects:
               customer_data.append(objects.name)
    response_data = json.dumps(customer_data)
    return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type='application/json')
```

urls.py

```
...
url(r'^change_date_view/', 'module.views.change_transaction_date'),
```

Jquery:

```
$('button_handler').on('click', function() { 
 var new_date_value = $(date_field_selector).val()
 $.ajax({ 
    url: "/change_date_view/",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
       new_date: button_handler,
      },
    success:function(data) { 
      //build your html via javascript with response data
       }
 })

})
```

Comment: I wanted to put two buttons on the list - previous month and next month which would change the month. I think AJAX is the better way to do this kind of stuff? Or can this be done simpler using forms?

Comment: You can use forms regardless of whether it is an ajax POST or not. I would do this with both ajax and django forms, although it really just depends if you want to prevent the page from reloading or not.

Comment: The page may reload, it is not an issue for me. I created a simple form where you put a month number and it filters the transactions by this month, but i want only next and previous buttons, with field to enter number hidden. I can do it with HiddenInput widget, but it would require me to have an autoincrementing field in the form and I cannot make this work